# Writing string to file doesn't throw error, but no file exists

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to save a CSV file to the Documents folder on iOS. The `write(to:atomically:encoding:)` doesn't throw an error, but when I got to load the file I get the error:

> The file “test.csv” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

How can I resolve this? Also, if I try to put the file in a folder in the Documents directory, it consistently fails writing the file saying there is "no folder named "test.csv"". I tried using .txt instead of .csv and got the same error.

My write block

```
    let dobString = NEKFormatter.dateOfBirth.string(from: dob)

    // TODO: File Naming Scheme
    let fileName = "test.csv"

    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last!
    let destDir = documentsDirectory
    let destPath = destDir.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    // Attempt to save file to patient folder. If no patient folder exists, create it.
    do {
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destDir.absoluteString) {
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: destDir, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
        }
        print(destPath)
        try csvString.write(to: destPath, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        filePath = destPath.absoluteString // Global variable
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Error writing file: \(error.localizedDescription),")
    }
```

My load block

```
        let rawDataPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)

        do {
            let csvString = try String(contentsOf: rawDataPath, encoding: .utf8)                
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription, #file, #line)
        }
```

Comment: Are you calling one after the other? Did you try to print the path in both cases?

Comment: I write the file, post a notification to the default `NSNotificationCenter` and then read the file. Printing the path reveals idententical paths.

Comment: Actually, here is the output before:
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8708D2ED-4A3C-4F6D-A389-1EBB83AAA6BB/Documents/test.txt

And after:
file:/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8708D2ED-4A3C-4F6D-A389-1EBB83AAA6BB/Documents/test.txt -- file:///

Comment: If I use `URL(string: filePath)` instead when I read the file, I do get identical URLs, but still the same error.

Comment: I don't understand why are you even transforming the URL to a string and back?

Comment: Ultimately the path will be stored in Core Data which requires it to be a string.

Comment: You cannot save absolute paths in core data because the sandbox directory changes when the app is updated. You always need to save a relative path and build the full path from `documentDirectory`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that here, but since the app isn't updating here it should still work, no?

Comment: The app is updated everytime you reinstall from Xcode but yes, it should work.

Comment: Works if I store the relative path and fetch the `documentDirectory` every time. However I still am getting an error if I try to put the file in a folder in the `documentDirectory` (Documents/MyFolder/test.csv) "Error writing file: The folder “test.csv” doesn’t exist."

Comment: I think you are not creating the intermediate directory correctly. The code in you question says "if directory exists then create directory", while it should be "if directory does not exist..."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144481/discussion-between-jjatie-and-sulthan).